# Create a bean in blueprint from an external bundle

Tags: apache-camel, bundle, osgi-bundle, karaf, blueprint-osgi

I am using Camel in Karaf with blueprint xml and I want to create a bean with the class coming from a different bundle.

```
<blueprint>
   ...
   <bean id="token-validation" class="com.xxx.security.JwtTokenValidator" init-method="init" >
      <property name="realm" value="${auth.realm}"/>
   </bean>
   ...
   <camelContext>
      <route id="route.EventsNotify" routePolicyRef="token-validation">
      ...
   </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

**JwtTokenValidator** class is located in another bundle, that extends the Camel's RoutePolicySupport, that's why it is applied in route route.EventsNotify.

```
    public class JwtTokenValidator extends RoutePolicySupport {      
       @Override
       public void onExchangeBegin(Route route, Exchange exchange) {
          super.onExchangeBegin(route, exchange);
          checkAuthorizationHeader(exchange);
       }    
      ...
   }
```

This bundle has some dependencies and classes like the aforementioned one, in order to be used in many projects. Write once and applied in many projects instead of coping the same code again and again.

Unfortunately this is not working, I am getting the following error in stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.xxx.security.JwtTokenValidator to org.apache.camel.spi.RoutePolicy
```

I cannot understand why, because the class is extending RoutePolicySupport which in terms implements the desired RoutePolicy interface.

If I move the class to the same bundle it is working, but I need to have it in a seperate bundle for the reasons that I explained before.

Could someone tells me where I am wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look at the OSGi blueprint documentation, you need to setup this a bit differently with a service/reference or something (cant recall 100% on top of my head)

Comment: Check also to which Camel each bundle is wired. It may be that your bean implements a `RoutePolicy` interface which is loaded by another classloader. How did you installa Camel inside Karaf?

Comment: I am using the karaf-maven-plugin which assemblies a full Apache Karaf. Camel is loaded as a startupFeatures of that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import all required Classes (org.apache.camel.spi.RoutePolicy, ...) to current Bundle's classLoader. If you are building your bundle with maven-bundle plugin, you can do it like this:

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            ...
            <Import-Package>
              ...,
              org.apache.camel.spi*;version=[min_version, max_version),
              ...
            </Import-Package>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```